# c++ Opengl handle elements drawn

Tags: c++, opengl

I am currently working on a game and I want to know if there is any way of handling with the elements i am drawing . For example : if i draw in a loop 100 cubes , how can i show / hide the cube number 15 or 63 or n ... I thought that initializing elements in a list would work , but i didn't find any property of it that could help.

```
GLuint cube;
cube = glGenLists(1);

glNewList(cube,GL_COMPILE);

for(int i = -30; i < 3; i++) {
  for(int j = -30; j < 3; j++) {
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(i*2.0,0,j * 2.0);
    Dcube();

    glPopMatrix();
   }
}
glEndList();
```

//something like : glDeleteList(cube); but that only works with entire list not with individual objects..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a display list, very good. So now you're back to using your regular language primitives to simply call that function.

```
std::array<bool, 100> cubes;
std::fill(cubes.begin(), cubes.end(), true);
cubes[15] = false;
cubes[63] = false;

for (bool drawCube : cubes) {
    if (drawCube) {
        // move a bit, perhaps using glTranslate
        glCallList(cube);
    }
}
```

OpenGL isn't your statekeeper. It just draws what you tell it to, you're responsible for keeping your objects.